# What is wrong with my snake vine (Hibbertia scandens)

Tags: plant-health

Last year I planted some snake vines (Hibbertia scandens). This spring they have really taken off.

But last week I noticed leaves on one of them were a bronze colour rather than glossy green. This now seems to have spread to a couple of the other plants. On the plant that first showed the problem, the affected leaves are starting to curl. But the growing shoots still look good and are noticeably longer every few days.

Any idea what the problem is? Any suggestion what the treatment is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share how frequently are the plants being watered and what is the type of soil they are planted?

Answer (score 1):

My snake vine has similar symptoms and is about 2 years old. It’s still growing and flowering although perhaps not as vigorously as it should. I suspect a fungal root problem from overwatering. I remove the affected leaves every week or so and now only water when it hasn’t rained for a week or more. I could also try spraying the leaves with a fungicide but haven’t yet.

Comment: Perhaps you could share a photo of it.